# ASP.net MVC4 Grid in EF data Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview

I'm trying to use [GRID.MVC](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/) in my project, but i got this error `System.NotSupportedException: The Skip method is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The OrderBy method must be called before the Skip method.` at line 27 at  `_grid.cshtml` file :

```
 Ligne 25 : @helper RenderGridBody()
Ligne 26 : {
Ligne 27 :     if (!Model.ItemsToDisplay.Any())
Ligne 28 :     {
Ligne 29 :     <tr class="grid-empty-text">
```

and this's my view :

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Add(item => item.OFFRE_ID).Titled("Custom column title").SetWidth(110);
                        columns.Add(item => item.REGION.NOM).Sortable(true);
                        columns.Add(item => item.DESCRIPTION).Sortable(false);
                        columns.Add(item => item.OFFRE_DATE).Sortable(true);
                    }).WithPaging(20)
```

Please how to fix it ?

Comment: Just give to your grid an ordered input (I suppose it's ItemsToDisplay).

Comment: Add an OrderBy() after you DB query (I don't see code, I suppose it's where you set ItemsToDisplay).

Comment: @Adriano Do you know how to activate Filtrable because I used this form `columns.Add(item => item.OFFRE_DATE).Filtrable(true);` it show me the icon but when i click on it the pop up dosn't show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so you know, `.WithPaging` causes this. It makes the GridView accept only sorted list. That means that passing an unsorted list will throw an exception.

```
// Passing this to the gridview will throw an exception because it is not sorted.
var offre = db.OFFRE.Include(o => o.REGION);
```

The solution is to "order" your list before passing it into the grid view.

```
var offre = db.OFFRE
    .Include(o => o.REGION)
    .OrderBy(c => c.OFFRE_ID); // This converts the list into a sorted list.

return View(offre);
```

Answer (score 0):

To Slove this Problem I had to Add OrderBy in the Controler result like this :

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var offre = db.OFFRE.Include(o => o.REGION);
            return View(offre.OrderBy(c => c.OFFRE_ID));
        }
```